# `delete.enabled=true` not deleting the record in MySQL through JDBC sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

My config file of sink contains the following configurations -

```
...
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
"tasks.max": "1",
"topics": "DELETESRC",
"insert.mode": "upsert",
"batch.size": "50000",
"table.name.format": "DELETESRC",
"pk.mode": "record_key",
"pk.fields": "ID,C_NO",
"delete.enabled": "true",
"auto.create": "true",
"auto.evolve": "true",
"max.retries": "10",
"retry.backoff.ms": "3000",
"mode": "bulk",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
"transforms": "ValueToKey",
"transforms.ValueToKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
"transforms.ValueToKey.fields": "ID,C_NO"
...
```

I am able to use upsert using the keys but not able to use the delete mode in the JDBC sink.
I configured the topic `DELETESRC` as `cleanup.policy=compact`, `delete.retention.ms=0`.
I created a KSQL stream as with 4 columns (`ID,CMP,SEG,C_NO`) and using the insert into statements in KSQL to push the data.

```
INSERT INTO DELETESRC VALUES ('null','11','D','1','3')
INSERT INTO DELETESRC VALUES ('null','11','C','1','4')
INSERT INTO DELETESRC VALUES ('null','12','F','1','3')
```

But when I am doing `INSERT INTO DELETESRC VALUES ('null','11','null','null','3')`, the sink is updating the table as `11,null,null,3`.
I have looked into other answers in stack-overflow but those solutions did not work.

**Am I doing any mistake in creating a tombstone record?**

I tried other ways in insert statement in KSQL but the delete operation is not occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to generate a proper tombstone message you need to provide a keyed message with `null` value. In the example you don't show null value.

---

In order to not lose events due to high consumer lag, I guess you need to increase the [`delete.retention.ms`](http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#brokerconfigs):

> The amount of time to retain delete tombstone markers for log
> compacted topics. **This setting also gives a bound on the time in which
> a consumer must complete a read if they begin from offset 0 to ensure
> that they get a valid snapshot of the final stage (otherwise delete
> tombstones may be collected before they complete their scan)**.

Comment: Can you please give me an example regarding the tombstone record? How can I insert that into stream so that it can be ingested into the topic?

Comment: @SanjayNayak Do tou have a source connector that replicates data from MySQl to Kafka and then a sink connector that reads from kafka and replicates back to MySQL?

Comment: No source connector is a CSV file that reads data and loads it into MySQL. My source is a CSV file. For the above one I was checking how delete.enabled works by creating a stream.

Comment: @SanjayNayak OK. So you need to write a simple producer and generate tombstone messages. Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61195652/how-to-produce-a-tombstone-avro-record-in-kafka-using-python/61195822#61195822

Comment: @SanjayNayak Any luck?

Comment: Sorry for that. I have not yet tried. There was some other requirement. So couldn't see into it. I will surely let you know

Comment: It worked. The tombstones are getting generated but in the key I am not able to see the key in record format. The key is coming as String format. The values are in AVRO. I checked the schema registry. I have the schema for the key.